# Table of images not resizing properly

Tags: html, html-table

The table I am creating consists of images only. It is a simple table of 2 rows, the first row spans the entire row. The second row has 3 columns. The images by default are large, so my program when executed is suppose to resize the entire table and images by 50%.

What actually happens, is that the images are scaled by 50% which is correct, but the table does not seems to scale. I get whitepaces in the second row between the images. Below is something I get.

How could I remove the whitespace so that image2, image3 and image 4 are next to each other.

```
---------------------------------
|           image 1             |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     image2     |  whitespace |   image 3     |  whitespace |  image4  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Table</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style type"text/css" media="screen">
/*Global Styles*/

table.sig img {
    width: 50%; !important;
    height: auto; !important;
    white-space: nowrap; !important;
}    

</style>
</head>
<body>
<table class="sig" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><img src="file:///header.png"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="file:///facebook.png"></a></td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="file:///profile.png"></a></td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="file:///website.png"></a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You got the white spaces because of your `50%` width: Actually each image will take `50%` of the width of its parent but the rest `50%` will remain empty.

You need to reset this width to `100%` fo the second row images like this:

```
table.sig img {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

table.sig a img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

**Demo:**

```css
/*Global Styles*/

table.sig img {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

table.sig a img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table class="sig" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/LZuF7Ua.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/LZuF7Ua.jpg"></a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/LZuF7Ua.jpg"></a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/LZuF7Ua.jpg"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I added the code and it did not workas expected. The first row image is resized to 50% which correct, but the second row of images are still at 100%, but the whitespace is gone. How do I also resize the second row images to 50% and get rid of the whitespace. Your demo snippet shows the problem also.

Comment: You can't keep the `50%` width and remove the white spaces, if you set `50%` the white spaces will take the rest `50%`.